# Accessing QML's LayoutMirroring attached property from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The [`LayoutMirroring`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-layoutmirroring.html) QML attached property allows switching the directionality of an item from left-to-right to right-to-left, or vice versa. I would like to access an item's current `LayoutMirroring` values from C++ code, extending a QML application. I understand that the `qmlAttachedPropertiesObject` function can be used to access attached properties from C++, as explained in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-extending.html#attached-properties), but I don't know where I can find the class that represent this specific property in C++.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by accessing **it's current values** ?.. What are those **its**? Can you please describe a little more! But I'm sure that **any _it's_** values can be accessed or made available from and to C++ code respectively.. Making the values available to C++ code can be done by calling a 'Q_INVOKABLE' slot from the JavaScript code. I cannot interpret your use case correctly, so I'm just telling my opinion.

Comment: What I meant by **it's** was a specific item's values. I've edited the question so that it would be more clear (I hope).

Comment: And about the solution with a `Q_INVOKABLE` slot, I think it would work, but it would require me to change the QML code using the C++ object in question, and I was hoping to avoid that. The `LayoutMirroring` can be inherited by items from their parents, so instead of changing just one place, I would need to change a lot more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to read and write attached properties easily with QQmlProperty class since Qt5.

Simple `main.qml` file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
    LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
}
```

Simple C++ code to read above `LayoutMirroring.enabled` attached property:

```
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
view.show();

QQuickItem* rootItem = view.rootObject();
qDebug() << QQmlProperty::read(rootItem, "LayoutMirroring.enabled", qmlContext(rootItem));
```

Console output:

```
=> QVariant(bool, true)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not working on that anymore, but this sounds like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
id: parentRect
property alias layoutValue : LayoutMirroring.enabled// ? true : false;// Read Only
LayoutMirroring.enabled: false
LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
width: 300; height: 50
color: "yellow"
border.width: 1

Row {
    anchors { left: parent.left; margins: 5 }
    y: 5; spacing: 5

    Repeater {
        model: 5

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            opacity: (5 - index) / 5
            width: 40; height: 40

            Text {
                text: index + 1
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

```
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer app(createApplication(argc, argv));
    QScopedPointer viewer(QmlApplicationViewer::create());

    viewer->setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer->setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/Test/main.qml"));
    QDeclarativeProperty propLayout(viewer->rootObject(),"layoutValue");
    QDeclarativeProperty propLayoutMargin(viewer->rootObject(),"anchors.leftMargin");

    qDebug() showExpanded();

    return app->exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, but like I said in the comment to the question, this method will require me to add such a property alias to any element I intend to read the LayoutMirroring property from, and it doesn't take advantage of the inheritance feature. I would like, for instance to read the value of the LayoutMirroring property for one of inner rectangles in this example, without modifying it.

Comment: Actually, it should be accessible from C++ like the other property **anchors.leftMargin**, but it couldn't be accessed directly. I have started a post on Qt Developers forum itself. They replied me that it might be a bug. So I have to file it as a bug. For now, I think this is the only method that occurs to me simple.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you can post the link to the bug here. I think I'd like to subscribe, and in the unlikely event that anyone ever reads this question, they might be interested as well.

Comment: [Bug Link to anchor.mirrored problem with QDeclarativeProperty](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-23427)